# How to interpret this database assignment?

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on an assignment concerning a simple database.

The instructions are given as:

Create a small database for "products", 
give each product 3 or so attributes in a related table, 
and then provide URL's for updating all aspects of those objects.

```
Create
Read
Update
Delete
List
Search
(For Products:)
Add Attribute
Remove Attribute
```

I am confused as to whether the Attributes are supposed to fixed categories that are the same for all products, and that deleting the attribute simply clears the cell, OR if it means that attributes are intended to be dynamically added, and that each product should be capable of having different categories of attributes.

In the second case, deleting an attribute would get rid of the entire category.

Comment: I don't think an attribute is a category. I think it's something like Colors, sizes, etc'.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: More like Colour, Size, etc (of an object of a product type). (Which I expect is what you meant.)

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is unclear and you should ask your instructor.

The straighforward interpretation of

> Create a small database for "products", give each product 3 or so
>   attributes in a related table, and then provide URL's for updating all
>   aspects of those objects.

is that there are some "products" (ie product types rather than individual objects) each of which has its own current set of attributes and its own table that records the current "objects" of that type and the attribute values of each one.

You more or less have the choice of recording a table for each product type P with:

- (*object*,*A*) rows like "object *object* is a P product whose attribute A is *A* and attribute ..." with `Add Attribute` implemented by DDL
- (*object*,*attribute*,*value*) rows like "object *object* is a P product whose *attribute* attribute is *value*" with `Add Attribute` implemented by DML

(The latter approach is called "EAV" and leads to obscure queries and foregoing of most of the supportive functionality of a DBMS. I only mention it because given the vaguenss of the question maybe it's wanted as a solution nevertheless.)

Re "attributes are intended to be dynamically added": Either of these allows each database state to have its own set of attributes for a product. Remember that there is both DDL and DML. Also, you seem to allow that "attribute" might mean "attribute value" but the former choice seems much more likely.

Re "deleting an attribute would get rid of the entire category": The assignment asks you to record "all aspects" of *objects* that are given product types, not of *products*. So it doesn't matter whether you ever "get rid of the entire category" (of a product).

(Clearly give and justify your interpretation of the assignment. If there is more than one interpretation that you think likely, do that for each.)